# trying to write a function that removes licensing from a text file but getting "local variable "fout" referenced before assignment

Tags: python

```py
def antipreamble(file_name):
    """Removes the preamble from a text file"""
    try: 
        fin = open(file_name, "r")
        print(f"Opened {file_name} successfully")
    except:
        print(f"Sorry - could not open {file_name}")
    i = 0
    for line in fin:
        if "*** START OF" in line:
            text_start = i
        if "*** END OF" in line:
            text_end = i
        i += 1
    fin.seek(0)
    i = 0
    
    newfile_name = file_name[:-4] +"_new.txt"
    try:
        fout = open(newfile_name, "r+")
        print(f"Opened {newfile_name} successfully")
    except:
        print(f"Sorry - could not open {newfile_name}")
   
    i = 0
    for lines in fin:
        if i > text_start and i < text_end:
            fout.write(lines)
        i += 1
        
   
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

tried adding

`global fout`

but did nothing.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Do you see "Sorry - could not open..."? You may be falling into your `except` case

Comment: Just remove all that exception handling. You will then actually see the problem you are having, instead of creatin6 a different problem

Comment: Never except on Exception, that will most likely cause you more problem than solve any.

Comment: The final loop can be reached if the attempt to open the output file fails, in which case `fout` hasn't been defined. Just printing an error message is insufficient to "handle" the error.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
        fout = open(newfile_name, "r+")
```

I don't recommend that.
Using a write mode of `"w"` would more
clearly express your intent.

---

Avoid explicit `.close()`, and prefer to
routinely use a context manager:

```
        with open(newfile_name, "w") as fout:
            ...
            fout.write( ... )
```

Definitely avoid `try` statements that
do not actually handle / fix a specific error condition.
Much better to let the error bubble up the call
stack and display a helpful diagnostic message.

---

It's unclear exactly what format the input file is in.
Notice that this condition is exclusive:

```
        if i > text_start and i < text_end:
```

Prefer inclusive:

```
        if i >= text_start and i <= text_end:
```

if you intend to display lines that begin
with those START / END OF markers.

---

Identifier names really matter.
They strongly affect how we reason about code.

You wrote this perfectly sensible line:

```
    for line in fin:
```

Later you wrote:

```
    for lines in fin:
```

Prefer singular here.
The plural identifier you chose would be more
appropriate in an assignment like `lines = fin.readlines()`.

---

Seeking to start-of-file is a nice technique,
and so is maintaining that pair of line indexes.
But we could produce the same effect with just
a single pass and a boolean flag.

Init `selected = False`.
Open files for read and for write.
Scan each input line.
If it's a START OF marker then set `selected = True`.
If selected, then write current line to the output file.
If we scan an END OF marker, then clear the selected flag.

This approach allows handling input files that
have multiple selected chunks, that is,
that have more than one START OF marker.

Comment: Better yet, use `for line in islice(fin, text_start, text_end):` (adjusting the arguments to `islice` as necessary to handle  the clusivity properly).